# Some confusion with multiset index notation,

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm trying to use this multiset notation

$\Gamma= \{(\gamma_1,\mu_1), ... (\gamma_k, \mu_k)\}$

now, I know that a set (compared with a list) is inherently unordered.

So when I refer to elements in this set $\Gamma$ can I say

"...some pair $(\gamma_k, \mu_k)$ in $\Gamma$ ..."

or by using the index $k$, I am incorrectly only referring to the last pair in the set?  Which wouldn't make sense, since a set is not ordered.

So is it correct to refer to an arbitrary pair in this set as $(\gamma_k, \mu_k)$ or use another index... such as $(\gamma_j, \mu_j)$ for $j \le k$?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing $\Gamma = \{(\gamma_1,\mu_1),\ldots,(\gamma_k,\mu_k)\}$ you have implicitly ordered the (multi)set $\Gamma$. This might not be part of the structure of $\Gamma$, but $(\gamma_k,\mu_k)$ certainly refers to the "last" element in the notation, so once you refer to that element using the letter $k$ you are using the implicit ordering.

In short, just use a different letter. You're probably not at a shortage.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I just finished reading up a bit on multisets.  If $\mu_j$ denotes the multiplicity of $\gamma_j$, then my construction of this set is really just an (ordered) set of distinct pairs, right? And that it's not actually a multiset ... thanks,

Comment: It's fine to write it like this and then pretend that $\Gamma$ does not have an ordering; you can forget about the ordering all you want. But you still did (implicitly, if nothing else), give one at some point. I doubt this is very important (but I don't have a lot of context for the question).